# Gun not giving damage to player but showing to the person who fired gun that player is dead

Tags: lua, roblox

so I have this code at a local script but when I shoot someone it shows for me that the person is dead but for the person and other players the player that was shot is still alive. the handgun script is at a localScript.

Comment: You should include you code in your question.

Comment: no man the code is all right its prob something else

Comment: This is expected. Changes made in LocalScripts are not replicated to other players. You need the code that handles the gun damage to be processed by a server Script for everyone to see it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote events in replicatedstorage. So do

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Eventname:FireServer(put variables here,2nd variable)
```

and then on a new server script (can be in the gear) do:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.Eventname.OnServerEvent(this would be the player,now comes the variables)
```

--put whatever you want here
end)

It's been a while since i made anything on roblox so this may not work.

Comment: alright it worked as I searched about the remote event stuff tysm